# GEMV BLAS and cuBLAS missing the "conjugate-only" ordering option?

Tags: c++, multiplication, blas, cublas, cblas

I have a question about the BLAS and cublas interface and how to do a particular matrix-vector multiplication.

I have a call that I currently do with `cblas_zgemv` and gives the correct result.

Basically I have a complex 3x3 matrix `A` and a complex vector `v` (3 components), in c-ordering all contiguous, and I want to multiply the hermitian-conjugate (conjugate and transpose) of the matrix to the vector.
This call can be made with cblas by calling

```
std::complex<double> const alpha=1.0;
std::complex<double> const beta=0.0;
cblas_zgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasConjTrans, 3 /*A size*/, 3/*A size*/, &alpha, A_pointer, 3 /*A stride*/, v_pointer, 1, &beta, result_pointer, 1 /*result_stride*/)
```

It looks as if this cannot be implemented by the BLAS interface.
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/dc1/group__complex16__blas__level2_gafaeb2abd9fffa7442b938dc384aeaf47.html#gafaeb2abd9fffa7442b938dc384aeaf47

The reason seems to be that BLAS doesn't have the "conjugate-only" option in the
"trans" argument.

The equivalent call in BLAS (not cblas) would be:

```
gemv( trans , 3, 3, alpha, A_pointer, 3, v_pointer, 1, beta, result_pointer, 1);
```

The `trans` options are only `N` (no-transpose, i.e. tranpose in C-ordering), `T` (tranpose, i.e no-transpose in C), `C` (conjugate-transpose, only-conjugate in C).

By symmetry, there another combination missing, something like `CO` ("conjugate-only" --without transpose--, which would correspond to conjugate-tranpose in C-ordering).

So, it seems that there is an inconvenient hole in BLAS for **complex** elements.
What is worst, this limitation seems to propagate to CUDA BLAS (cuBLAS) which has the same interface as BLAS basically.
Making a cuBLAS call would be my final goal.
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemv

Like in BLAS, cuBLAS has only three options (via enum) for the transposition option: `CUBLAS_OP_N`, `CUBLAS_OP_T`, `CUBLAS_OP_H`.

**Am I missing something obvious? Is this a known limitation and there is a well known workaround?**

---

NOTE: I know that perhaps this particular case can be implemented with GEMM in a case with dimension `1xn`, but then the same argument can be made about GEMM, it lacks the the "conjugate-only" option.

Comment: I checked the lastest `cublas_api.h` and noticed there's a `CUBLAS_OP_CONJG` option with comment `/* conjugate, placeholder - not supported in the current release */`.

Comment: @Kh40tiK  Good catch. This confirms that there is a hole in BLAS (and cublas) and where to look for when it is implemented. It is notable how this problem is little mentioned around internet.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to do conjugate only with standard BLAS API.

But there is a easy way to do Conjugate only. When you have a row major matrix, this can be done by setting `CblasConjTrans` and using `CblasColMajor` instead of `CblasRowMajor` and vice versa for col major matrix. To summarise

```
// Conj Transpose
cblas_zgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasConjTrans, 3 /*A size*/, 3/*A size*/, &alpha, A_pointer, 3 /*A stride*/, v_pointer, 1, &beta, result_pointer, 1 /*result_stride*/)

// No transpose  and No Conj
cblas_zgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, 3 /*A size*/, 3/*A size*/, &alpha, A_pointer, 3 /*A stride*/, v_pointer, 1, &beta, result_pointer, 1 /*result_stride*/)

// Only Trans
cblas_zgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasTrans, 3 /*A size*/, 3/*A size*/, &alpha, A_pointer, 3 /*A stride*/, v_pointer, 1, &beta, result_pointer, 1 /*result_stride*/)

//Only conj()
cblas_zgemv(CblasColMajor, CblasConjTrans, 3 /*A size*/, 3/*A size*/, &alpha, A_pointer, 3 /*A stride*/, v_pointer, 1, &beta, result_pointer, 1 /*result_stride*/)
```

If you want a direct way, try using BLIS library.

Comment: This is fine but I think this is cblas only. not blas. blas is usually the one generalized to other contexts (cuda) which is what I intent to do eventually.